# Getting an error as unable to get property "dolayout" in salesforce console

Tags: console

Getting an error as unable to get property "dolayout" of undefined or null reference URL  in salesforce console

Comment: When does this happen?

Comment: From Today only it started and issue is not reproducible in sandbox  only facing this issue in production.

Comment: Yes but when? What's the context? (Visualforce page, trigger...)

Comment: Basically ,they get this error when they trying to click on button on visualforce page

Comment: Ok. So we can help you only if you provide the visualforce page code and the controller code  behind this page.

Comment: This is happening with NA17 as well. Just started this morning. Salesforce had to have changed something for us to all be experiencing this issue today.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Widespread Salesforce bug

Comment: What's the deal? So many people are affected by this issue, but no one's up-voting the question...

Answer (score 3):

Resolution: This is now a Salesforce bug. See details [Here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000f07LQAQ) and click on the button that says 'This Issue Affects Me' to be notified of a resolution.  Looks like planned fix is Summer at the latest, the response on my case said it may be sooner.

---

We are experiencing the same issue when users log in using IE10 or IE11 (necessary for legacy systems) and attempting to navigate to a Service Console app. See attached image of the error we are experiencing. We opened a case with Salesforce. Some users can click past the error and start using Console apps, but others cannot. Even when logging in as those users I can not reproduce but enough users reported the error that we opened a case.

After speaking with Salesforce, they have many reports of the issue. We are working with them to reproduce the error. They will be researching/working on it and reporting back when they have more information.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a case # that others can reference when contacting support? I think that is appropriate???? @AdrianLarson

Comment: Sure, the case number I have open with Salesforce is: 15903744.  So if anyone opens their own case or chats with Salesforce support, they should be able to reference that case number.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug on Salesforce's side and not something caused by any customer implementation. It will happen intermittently when you are using CTI with the console. Salesforce is working on a fix. You can track the issue to be notified when the fix is released here:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000f07LQAQ

Answer (score 0):

I have a user who is receiving this error too. It only occurs when she tries to view our service console application. There is no custom code or customized visualforce pages involved for us. She simply selects the app from the dropdown, and it throws the error. Like you, this only started today. So I'm thinking it's some underlying change on Salesforce's part. My user is using Firefox - what browser are you using?

Comment: This is not an answer. please post as comment

Answer (score 0):

the error we are seeing is 
Unable to properly "doLayout" of undefined or null reference URL: underline: underline Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT6.1:Wow64:trident/7.0: .NET CLR 2.0.50727: .NET CLR 3.5.30729: .NET CLR3.0.30729: Media Center PC6.0: .NET

Comment: Cannot flag as not an answer cause mods are declining these flags so not sure what to do here. Review is only allowing me to flag. Mods - this should be an addition to the questions and not a comment @AdrianLarson

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing this as well, confirming that we were moved to a new instance over the weekend. Trust is showing current disruptions on those instances as well.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please post as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce support tells us this is a known issue that they are working to correct. The fix is scheduled to be corrected in the Summer '17 release.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000f07LQAQ

**Workaround**

1. Reload a browser window
2. User Console and normal page at each Tabs separately

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this today by turning off the users compatibility mode in IE11. You could also use Chrome as a work around.